# jqGrid not rendering JSON data into grid

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

Even though my action method is returning data in JSON format, however, the jqGrid control is not able to render it.

Here's the code of the method that returns data in JSON format.

```
ContactContext db = new ContactContext();

    //
    // GET: /Contact/

    public JsonResult ContactList(int? selectedContact)
    {

        IQueryable<Contact> contacts = db.Contacts;

        var contactsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contacts.ToList());

        return Json(contactsJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Data returned by 'ContactList' action method of Controller class:

```
        contactsJson    ""[{\"ContactId\":1,\"FirstName\":\"John\",\"LastName\":\"Doe\",\"EMail\":\"john.doe@gmail.com\",\"Phone\":\"7458593847\",\"BusinessName\":\"microsoft\"},{\"ContactId\":2,\"FirstName\":\"Jack\",\"LastName\":\"Davos\",\"EMail\":\"jack.davos@microsoft.com\",\"Phone\":\"348945485\",\"BusinessName\":\"microsoft\"},{\"ContactId\":3,\"FirstName\":\"Mike\",\"LastName\":\"Strong\",\"EMail\":\"mike.strong@google.com\",\"Phone\":\"950595959\",\"BusinessName\":\"google\"}]"
```

jqGrid code:

```
function populateContactList() {

    $("#ContactTable").jqGrid({
        url: "/Contact/ContactList",
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ["ID", "First Name", "Last Name", "EMail", "Phone", "Business Name"],
        colModel: [
            { name: "ContactId", index: "ContactId", width: 80 },
            { name: "FirstName", index: "FirstName", width: 200 },
            { name: "LastName", index: "LastName", width: 200 },
            { name: "EMail", index: "EMail", width: 300 },
            { name: "Phone", index: "Phone", width: 100 },
            { name: "BusinessName", index: "BusinessName", width: 200 },
        ],
        //data: result,
        mtype: 'GET',
        autowidth: true, 
        shrinkToFit: false,
        //loadonce: true,
        viewrecords: true,
        gridview: true,
        emptyrecords: "No records to display",
        jsonReader: {
            repeatitems: false,
            //page: function () { return 1; },
            root: function (obj) { return obj; },
            //records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
        },
        loadComplete: function () {},
        loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + '\n' +
                'textstatus: ' + textstatus + '\n' +
                'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
            alert('HTTP message body  (jqXHR.responseText: ' + '\n' + jqXHR.responseText);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(populateContactList);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your data is serialized twice,

one from line,

```
var contactsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contacts.ToList());
```

and second time from `JsonResult` action filter

```
return Json(contactsJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

sending json data like,

```
return Json(contacts.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

instead of

```
var contactsJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(contacts.ToList());

return Json(contactsJson, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

should work.

hope this helps.

Comment: +1 from me. I full agree with you. I want to add that adding `loadonce: true` is recommended because one didn't implemented server side paging, sorting and filtering/searching on the server side. One should consider to add `key:true` property in `ContactId` column of `colModel` to use the values as rowid and to remove unneeded `index` properties from all items of `colModel`. `autoencode: true` option is also recommended because one fill the grid with pure data and not with HTML fragments.

Comment: Thanks a lot @shakib. You are correct, it was getting serialized twice.

Comment: Thanks @Oleg for your inputs. Will keep it mind and make changes accordingly.